# reading data from a binary file

Tags: binary

```
000000 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 08 03
000010 17 10 15 27 00 00 01 00 FB 00 0A 00 00 00 38 FF
000020 01 00 FB 00 09 00 00 00 34 FF 01 00 FB 00 09 00
000030 00 00 31 FF 01 00 FB 00 08 00 00 00 2D FF 01 00
000040 FB 00 08 00 00 00 2A FF 01 00 FB 00 08 00 00 00
000050 26 FF 01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 24 FF 01 00 FB 00
000060 06 00 00 00 24 FF 01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 22 FF
000070 01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 24 FF 01 00 FB 00 06 00
000080 00 00 22 FF 01 00 FB 00 06 FF EB 00 22 FF 01 00
000090 FB 00 06 00 00 00 22 FF 01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00
0000A0 22 FF 01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 22 FF 01 00 FB 00
0000B0 06 00 00 00 1E FF 01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 1E FF
0000C0 01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 1E FF 01 00 FB 00 06 00
0000D0 00 00 1E FF 01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 1E FF 01 00
0000E0 FB 00 06 00 00 00 1E FF 01 00 FB 00 05 00 00 00
0000F0 1E FF 01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 1C FF 01 00 FB 00
000100 06 00 00 00 1C FF 01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 1C FF
000110 01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 1C FF 01 00 FB 00 06 00
000120 00 00 1C FF 01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 1C FF 01 00
000130 FB 00 06 00 00 00 1C FF 01 00 FB 00 05 00 00 00
```

Hi, im a noob trying to decode this binary file but to no avail, appreciate if anyone could help. The only thing that i know is that the data type is an unsigned char type. i tried  standard x86 double (8 byte) representation extraction but to no avail. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to have a header followed by a repeating pattern. Two of the bytes appear to be counting down mostly except for a blip at `FF EB`. Just guessing..  maybe it's temperature sensor data?

Comment: This question is lacking details such as where the data is from, what kind of information you're looking for etc.

Comment: it seems like the data consists of a sequence of 4-byte unsigned integers. Each line of the hexadecimal representation contains 16 bytes, which is equivalent to 4 integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any more details it's hard to draw many conclusions at all.

I think the best that can be done is to infer some high level structure, though even this might be disprovable if the full file was available.

For example the structure might be -

1. a 22 byte header, followed by
2. multiple records each of 10 bytes

   ```
   // header
   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   00 00 00 00 01 01 08 03
   17 10 15 27 00 00 

   // records
   01 00 FB 00 0A 00 00 00 38 FF 
   01 00 FB 00 09 00 00 00 34 FF 
   01 00 FB 00 09 00 00 00 31 FF 
   01 00 FB 00 08 00 00 00 2D FF 
   01 00 FB 00 08 00 00 00 2A FF 
   01 00 FB 00 08 00 00 00 26 FF 
   01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 24 FF 
   01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 24 FF 
   01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 22 FF 
   01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 24 FF 
   01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 22 FF 
   01 00 FB 00 06 FF EB 00 22 FF 
   01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 22 FF 
   01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 22 FF 
   01 00 FB 00 06 00 00 00 22 FF 
   ...
   ```

Knowing what the info is supposed to represent and where it comes from is essential to do any more.

Comment: As @megatonnage commented there is a blip of ff eb in this pattern

Comment: Hi Ian, i try generating the binary following your suggestion pattern & i could see result. Already post the example. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1   0   251 0   201 1   67  1   62  255
1   0   251 0   200 1   77  1   61  255
1   0   251 0   200 1   72  1   62  255
1   0   251 0   200 1   65  1   63  255
2 22 3 23 12 7 28 0 252 1 219 0 200 0 0 0 49 10 36 10 1 242 1 250 0 0 1
1   0   252 0   186 1   63  1   62  255
1   0   252 0   214 0   212 0   0   255
1   0   252 0   204 0   201 0   0   255
1   0   252 0   238 1   38  0   0   255
1   0   252 0   242 1   10  0   0   255
1   0   252 0   253 1   1   0   0   255
1   0   252 1   9   1   17  0   0   255
.....this type of pattern goes on for sometime
1   0   251 0   202 1   65  1   67  255
1   0   251 0   202 1   76  1   65  255
1   0   251 0   198 1   54  1   60  255
2 22 3 23 12 7 34 0 252 1 219 0 200 0 0 0 49 10 36 10 1 239 1 252 0 0 1
1   0   252 0   189 1   67  1   66  255
1   0   252 0   216 0   188 0   0   255
1   0   252 0   210 0   234 0   0   255
1   0   252 0   237 1   28  0   0   255
1   0   252 0   245 0   246 0   0   255

Hi Ian, thanks for your pattern suggestion that i follow & convert the hex to unsigned char & got result as above, the data start to make sense as portion 2 22 3 23 12 7 34 means date 22/3/23 and time 12:7:34. I just have to translate other data that are available.

Thanks again Ian Cook